# How to get sub properties in jQuery.each() function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In controller:

```
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = pageIndex,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = founduser
        };
        return jsonData;
```

In View:

```
function listItems(col, order, page, rows) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetUsers")',
        data: { col: col, order: order, page: page, rows: rows },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var tags = "<tr><th>Login id</th><th>First name</th><th>Middle name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Prefix</th><th>Suffix</th><th>Reset</th><th>Email</th><th></th></tr>";
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                    tags += "<tr id=row-" + item.UserID + ">" +
                                "<td>" + item.LoginID + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.MiddleName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.Prefix + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.Suffix + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.IsReset + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + item.SendEmail + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" +
                                "<a href=# class='ActivateItem' data-id = " + item.UserID + " item-data = " + item.LoginID + ">Activate</a> | " +
                                "<a href=/BaseAdmin/User/Details/" + item.UserID + ">Details</a></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#table-list").html(tags);
        }
    });
};
```

rows is an `IEnumerable array`, now how could I get the values of row and put on the table?

```
<table id="table-list">
</table>
```

I'm able to retrieve the values, but I can't display it using jQuery.each. Thanks for help!

Sample preview:

[image]

Comment: can you post the json you are receiving in the response

Comment: @3nigma actually that's my problem, I can't get the json results but as you can see on the controller part, there are data being returned.

Comment: use chrome and add console.log(response) at the beginning of your success function.  See if the json result is even getting returned properly.  If it's not, use John's recommendation.  Also, since you are calling an [HttpGet], you will need to `return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Comment: console was so helpful. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One you return a JSON result from your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = pageIndex,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = founduser
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

you can loop through the `rows` property in your AJAX `success` callback:

```
success: function (response) {
var tags = "<tr><th>Login id</th><th>First name</th><th>Middle name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Prefix</th><th>Suffix</th><th>Reset</th><th>Email</th><th></th></tr>";
$.each(response.rows, function (index, item) {
    tags += "<tr id=row-" + item.UserID + ">" +
                "<td>" + item.LoginID + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.MiddleName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.Prefix + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.Suffix + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.IsReset + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.SendEmail + "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                   "<a href=# class='ActivateItem' data-id = " + item.UserID + " item-data = " + item.LoginID + ">Activate</a> | " +
                   "<a href=/BaseAdmin/User/Details/" + item.UserID + ">Details</a>" +
                "</td>" + 
            "</tr>";
    });
    $("#table-list").html(tags);
}
```

Things that could be improved in this code:

- don't use string concatenations to generate a DOM tree. Use the [`jQuery( html, props )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) overload.
- don't hardcode the url of your `Details` anchors -> use url helpers to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller try:

```
return Json(jsonData);
```

That will return a JsonResult.